# Initializing properties of a Class in Swift

Tags: swift, class, initialization

Why does this code work:

```
class EquilateralTriangle {

    var sideLength: Double = 3.0
    var perimeter: Double {
            return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
}
```

And this does not:

```
class EquilateralTriangle {

    var sideLength: Double = 3.0
    var perimeter: Double = 3.0 * sideLength
}
```

Comment: Imagine that all the properties are initialized at the same time. On the second one, `sideLenght` isn't known yet, because `self` is not fully "initialized". On the first one, it's a `get`, a computed property. Each time you access the value, you re-calculate again with current value of `sideLength`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var perimeter: Double {
    return 3.0 * sideLength
}
```

is shorthand for this:

```
var perimeter: Double {
    get {
        return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
}
```

which is kind of sugar for this:

```
func permiter() -> Double {
    return 3.0 * sideLength
}
```

So it's a *computed property*, the thing with the braces is a function - any time the perimeter value is read, the function runs and returns 3 * sideLength using the current value for sideLength

```
var perimeter: Double = 3.0 * sideLength
```

is not valid - it would be trying to initialize the property with a default value, but that can't refer to other values. It would work as a compile-time constant expression, so if you changed it to 3.0 * 3.0.  But that would also mean something else, it wouldn't compute the value every time. You would be saying this property is just a Double, that has some value that you can change if you want, and its initial value is 9. That would mean it is not the right value for permiter if sideLength is ever changed from 3.